# How to enable Pylint extension to show "E202" error on VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, flake8

I wrote the code below on [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/):

```py
"""Say Hello"""

print("Hello"    )
```

Then, [Flake8 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.flake8) can show `E202` error for `print("Hello"    )` as shown below:

[image]

> whitespace before ')' Flake8(E202)

But, [Pylint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.pylint) cannot show `E202` error for `print("Hello"    )` as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I enable **Pylint extension** to show `E202` error on VSCode?

Comment: pylint and flake8 are different programs which have different sets of rules

Answer (score 1):

The **bad-whitespace** error has been removed from pylint. check this [issue](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/3512)

all messages are [here](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/messages_overview.html)

Comment: To second that, the reason it was removed is because the message is hard to maintain and it's auto-fixable by applying [``black``](https://pypi.org/project/black/) so there's not much value in checking it

Answer (score -1):

pylint does not have a rule to catch that type of issues.

If I use the CLI commands, I can see that pylint does not show this as a problem:

```
$ cat /tmp/a.py
print("Hello"  )

$ pylint /tmp/a.py
************* Module a
/tmp/a.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00)

$ flake8 /tmp/a.py
/tmp/a.py:2:15: E202 whitespace before ')'
```

So, the pylint extension does not show it.